# Alternative way to find all files in a folder and subfolders

Tags: linux, file, unix, grep, find

Is there any alternative for below command to find files in a folder and subfolders as well.

```
find . | egrep '\./[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+'
```

Note: I don't want directories I want to get only files

Comment: Note: I don't want directories I want to get only files

Comment: I think this question has no part with programming related. it is pure tool usage question...

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you could specify list of files extensions as your search options:

```
find . -type f -name "*.js" -o -name "*.ros" -o -name "*.php"
```

Above example, would only display file names with *.ros, *.php, and *.js as file extensions under specific folder and subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use find?
I am not sure from your question if you want to limit the depth.  If so:

```
find . -type f -depth 2 -print
```

If you just want to find files

```
find . -type f -print
```

If you just want to find directories

```
find . -type d -print
```

You can also use -ls if -print does not float your boat.

```
find . -type f -ls
```

Comment: What about if we are not sure about depth?

Comment: Leave it out.  -type f just finds files.

Comment: Grr AIX can't test. Might need -print at the end.

Comment: I already tried with find . -type f its not giving correct output

Comment: What output are you getting and why is it not correct?

Comment: Its working in ubuntu but not working in AIX , Iam checking why that is not working

Comment: check you don't have an alias for find.

Comment: find . | egrep '\./[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+'|wc -l   
    2838
find . -type f|wc -l
       1

Comment: Try invoking find as /usr/bin/find  I think you might have something else in your path called find.  It should work.